Foundry Slate text box layout
I have a function that returns a list of items separated by commas (see picture).
I would like to know how to display this in the same view as the function.
The default text box or list just puts it all one line.

The desired view would be:

25-0545-8-0008  TASK, B777, MAINT DEVICE NETWORK UPDATE,
99-0505-8-0009  INSP, *ETOPS VERIFICATION FLIGHT RQD -PCI DUE,
25-0524-8-0041  TASK, B777-224, BACKUP GEN OIL/FILTER CHANGE - ER,
25-0572-8-0283  TASK, GE90B, ENGINE INSP- ER,
25-0524-8-0200  TASK, B777, ENG IDG OIL/SCAVENGE FILT REPL ER

I have tried all widgets and some line break options with no help.

The Widget you are displaying the data in is expecting HTML, so you need to provide HTML to be formatted correctly.
For example the below should work:
var myArrayOfStrings = {{my_function}}
return return myArrayOfStrings.join('<br>');


where would you add that example?

almost perfect I figured out how to set it up in function but can we get ride of the ($) ?

7-2175-9-9001 CONVERTER, OZONE, CATALYTIC 777-200 ($)
25-3411-9-0002 PROBE, PITOT STATIC, RH 767/777 ($) *PMA
25-4732-9-9002 EXCHANGER, HEAT, THERMAL CTRL NGS ($)
25-2435-9-9001 BATTERY, AIRCRAFT FLT CTRLS DEDICATED 777 (LLP)($)
25-2560-9-0011 SLIDE, B777-200, #4 RH DOOR
25-5211-9-9001 RESERVOIR, ENTRY DOOR, 777-200 LLP KIT (+) ($)

oops never mind that was from my data. this worked perfect, Thanks so much for the help
